# Script to calculate fees not display result

Tags: javascript

```js
$('input[type=button]').on ('click', function () {
    var totalAmount = $('#amount').val(); // Cantidad a pagar -> 1200
   
}
$('#amount').val(totalAmount);
    var feeType     = $('#typefee option:selected').val()  || 24; // En cuantos meses, 6, 12, 24. Por defecto 24
    var tax         = 0.05; //Impuesto
    
    var totalAlreadyPay = $('#amountPayed').val() || 0; // Lo que ya se ha pagado -> 200
     
    if ((totalAmount && totalAmount > 0) || totalAlreadyPay > 0) {
        // En caso de haber pagado ya alguna parte
        totalAmount      = totalAmount - totalAlreadyPay
    } 
    $('#amount').val(totalAmount);
 
    // Total a pagar al mes en función del tipo de cuota: 6, 12, 24 meses
    var totalToPay = 0;
    totalToPay = (totalAmount / feeType) + (totalAmount / feeType) * tax;
 
    $('#totalamount').html(totalAmount);
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="amount">
<input type="text" id="amountPayed">
<select id="typefee">
    <option value="6">6 meses</option>
    <option value="12">12 meses</option>
    <option value="24">24 meses</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value="Calcular">
<div id="totalamount"></div>
```

This is my script, I do not understand why it's not displaying the result, I'm really new to javascript and I'm learning, I would appreciate it help me know why the result is not displayed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `}` in second line inside your click event you should remove it, check working snippet bellow.

**NOTE :** You should consider to use developers console in your browser because it will help you find the issue in your code, the console in this case shows :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

---

```js
$('input[type=button]').on ('click', function () {
    var totalAmount = $('#amount').val(); // Cantidad a pagar -> 1200
   
    var feeType     = $('#typefee option:selected').val()  || 24; // En cuantos meses, 6, 12, 24. Por defecto 24
    var tax         = 0.05; //Impuesto
    
    var totalAlreadyPay = $('#amountPayed').val() || 0; // Lo que ya se ha pagado -> 200
     
    if ((totalAmount && totalAmount > 0) || totalAlreadyPay > 0) {
        // En caso de haber pagado ya alguna parte
        totalAmount      = totalAmount - totalAlreadyPay
    } 
    $('#amount').val(totalAmount);
 
    // Total a pagar al mes en función del tipo de cuota: 6, 12, 24 meses
    var totalToPay = 0;
    totalToPay = (totalAmount / feeType) + (totalAmount / feeType) * tax;
 
    $('#totalamount').html(totalAmount);
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="amount">
<input type="text" id="amountPayed">
<select id="typefee">
    <option value="6">6 meses</option>
    <option value="12">12 meses</option>
    <option value="24">24 meses</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value="Calcular">
<div id="totalamount"></div>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the first `$('#amount').val(totalAmount);` is also extra